# dxa-web-application-java Cannot find repository and StorageException Errors

Tags: dxa, java

Tomcat logs the errors below, Does anyone know how to fix these?

### What I did.

I have a fully working .Net DXA with Experience Manager and want to learn how to use the Java DXA so I

- Followed the instructions to download and build the developer Java
  DXA code.
- Configured Tomcat for port 80 and deleted the ROOT.
- Renamed the `example-webapp.war` file to root.war
- Dropped the `Root.war` file in the Web-Apps folder
- Waited for Tomcat to deploy the Root application
- Edited `cd_dynamic_config.xml` to change the publication id and Host

```xml
    <Publications>
        <Publication Id="5">
            <Host Protocol="http" Domain="localhost" Port="80" Path=""/>
        </Publication>
    </Publications>
```

- Edited `cd_storage_conf.xml` with a copy of the settings in our working
  .net dxa site
- Restarted tomcat

### Errors

> 13:22:20.618 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR c.s.c.config.LazyRepositoryLocation - Cannot find repository at ../repository : File ../repository does not exist at path /C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/../repository
>
> 13:22:28.478 [Sessions cleaner thread] ERROR c.t.s.session.SessionServiceImpl - StorageException occurred while retrieving Session!
>   com.tridion.broker.StorageException: No Data Access Object Factory for internal_cd_session_db.  Check if the default file system is properly defined and ItemTypes defaultStorageId is correct.
>           at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAOFactoryForStorageId(StorageManagerFactory.java:656) ~[cd_datalayer-7.1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAOForStorageId(StorageManagerFactory.java:300) ~[cd_datalayer-7.1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionServiceImpl.getRightDAO(SessionServiceImpl.java:468) ~[cd_session-7.1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionServiceImpl.getExpiredSessions(SessionServiceImpl.java:74) ~[cd_session-7.1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.storage.session.SessionManagerImpl.performCleanup(SessionManagerImpl.java:226) [cd_session-7.1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.SessionsCleanerMonitor.run(SessionsCleanerMonitor.java:52) [cd_session-7.1.0.jar:na]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]

Comment: Is the `SessionWrapper` added in `cd_storage_conf.xml` (I guess it is and its `Id` is "internal_cd_session_db") and are the XPM jars indeed added to the lib folder?

Comment: Edited cd_storage_conf.xml to change id from "sessionDb" to "internal_cd_session_db" Now I get ERROR c.t.s.session.SessionServiceImpl - StorageException occurred while retrieving Session!
com.tridion.broker.StorageException: No Data Access Object for PreviewSession

Comment: Can you simply comment out the whole <Wrappers /> section in cd_storage_conf.xml and see if it works then?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happening when having the jars for Experience Manager in the lib folder of the application and not the corresponding configuration files. If you are not making use of Experience Manager, you will need to ensure not only to remove the related configuration files, as well as the jars that XPM relies on:

- `cd_session.jar`
- `cd_preview_webservice.jar`
- `cd_preview_web.jar`
- `cd_preview_ambient.jar`